# What can I use instead of std::string::pop_back in older C++ standard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c++03

I'm using Visual C++ 2008. I can't use `pop_back` because it became a member function of the string class in C++11.

What could I use instead since I can't use `pop_back`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), which I personally find a little more clear semantically than the `resize` alternative:

```
if (!s.empty())
  s.erase (s.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::string::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize):

```
if (!s.empty())
  s.resize(s.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand your question but if you want to append something to a std::string you can use

[std::string::append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)

and if you want to "shrink" it you can use

[std::string::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possibilites. Either to use member function erase or member function resize. for example

```
s.erase( s.size() - 1 );
```

or

```
s.resize( s.size() - 1 );
```

If you do not want to use push_back then you can substitute it for operator + or member function append.